# Constructing most powerful critical region basics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, likelihood-ratio

I've been trying to teach myself some of the fundamentals of statistics and would like to see if I'm in the right direction.

**Here's the problem:**

Construct the most powerful critical region of size $\alpha$ to test the null hypothesis $H_0: \theta=\theta_0$, where $\theta$ is the parameter of a binomial distribution $b(n,\theta)$ with a given value of $n$, against the alternative hypothesis $H_1: \theta=\theta_1<\theta_0$. Use $\theta_0=0.75$, $\theta_1=0.5$, $n=25$, and $\alpha=0.05$.

**My work:**

Since we have simple hypotheses, we can apply the Neyman-Pearson lemma. So, if $f(x;\theta)$ is the pmf we're working with, we have
$$\frac{f(x;\theta_1)}{f(x;\theta_0)}= \frac{ {25\choose x}(1/2)^x (1/2)^{25-x}}{{25\choose x}(3/4)^x (1/4)^{25-x}}= 2^{25}(1/3)^x.$$ Now, this ratio is decreasing in $x$, which means we reject $H_0$ for small enough $x$. So, we want to find $c$ such that $$\mathbb{P}(X\leq c \hspace{1mm}; \theta=0.75)=0.05$$
and, by computation, I found $$\mathbb{P}(X\leq 14 \hspace{1mm}; \theta=0.75) \approx 0.03$$ and $$\mathbb{P}(X\leq 15 \hspace{1mm}; \theta=0.75) \approx 0.07.$$
Hence, by Neyman-Pearson, a test that rejects when $X\leq 14$ is a UMP level $\alpha(=0.05)$ test. So, the most powerful critical region of size $0.05$ is $0\leq X \leq 14$.

I would very much appreciate any feedback/corrections/etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Anyway you look at it, the answer looks good.

You have discovered that the log likelihood ratio is linear:

$$\log\left(\frac{f(x;\theta_1)}{f(x;\theta_0)}\right) = 25\log(2) - x\log(3).$$

The left hand panel of the figure plots this.  (Since only the shape of the log likelihood ratio matters, no value axis is shown.)

[image: Figure]

This reflects the fact that the relative probability that $X$ came from $\theta_1$ compared to $\theta_0$ decreases as $X$ grows larger.  Those probabilities appear in the middle panel of the figure: red, peaking near $25\theta_1=12.5$, for $\theta_1$, and blue, peaking near $25\theta_0=18.75$, for $\theta_0$.  That suffices to show the UMP critical region must be some interval starting at $X=0$.

A good quantitative check of the result is afforded by the cumulative distribution functions, shown in the right panel with comparable colors.  The dotted horizontal line is at a value of $\alpha=0.05$.  The CDF corresponding to $\theta_0$ rises above $\alpha$ between $X=14$ and $X=15$, showing that the false positive rate must be less than $\alpha$ for the critical region $\{0,1,\ldots, 14\}$ but greater than $\alpha$ if $15$ is also included.  Consequently $\{0,1,\ldots, 14\}$ is the unique solution.